# Symfony Dotenv not always loading

Tags: php, symfony

Can someone help explain why environment variables loaded in through Symfony's Dotenv component are sometimes not being set?

I have an PHP application that makes several concurrent local HTTP requests (essentially calling another script). Each request loads tries to load the `.env` file, and use its data via `getenv()`. During every run, some of the requests load the information fine, while others do not. It almost seems like the Dotenv library's `load()` method works asynchronously.

My main script pools a bunch of HTTP requests using `GuzzleHttp`. Inside each request, I have the following code that tries to load and access the variables:

**index.php**

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = new \Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv();
$dotenv->load(dirname(__DIR__) . "/.env");

$instance = new App\Controllers\Controller();
```

**Controller.php**

```
$host     = getenv("DB_HOST");
$name     = getenv("DB_NAME");
$user     = getenv("DB_USER");
$password = getenv("DB_PASSWORD");

$this->client = new PDO(
    "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$name}",
    $user,
    $password,
    [
        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 600,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ]
);
```

On some requests, the values of these `getenv()` calls will be blank. If I re-run the script, other requests will be blank.

I tried moving the `Dotenv` loader calls inside the `Controller` method, that did not work.

I'm not sure if there is an error in my code, or I am misunderstanading how dotenv files are loaded.

---

Edit: System information

OS: `Windows 10 x64`

PHP version: `5.6.31`

Configure Command:

> cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"

Comment: Code seems correct. Try logging the env values right after the load call: maybe something after load but before your controller is overwriting them.

Comment: Also make sure wjatever serves thus cide is serving from one place only: if you have multiple installs, and other installs are being offered, maybe one of those is missing its .env file

Comment: Ah, it seems you were right. I can access the variables right before the controller constructor call, but not always inside the constructor. I guess they are being overwritten. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So it seems the issue is actually with however `getenv()` retrieves the variables. I switched to using `$_ENV` and it works everytime.

```
$host     = $_ENV["DB_HOST"];
$name     = $_ENV["DB_NAME"];
$user     = $_ENV["DB_USER"];
$password = $_ENV["DB_PASSWORD"];
```

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1636661/2755165) sheds some light on how `getenv` differs from `$_SERVER`. So my guess is that there is some disconnect with how `Dotenv` was saving variables, and `getenv` was retrieving them.

Comment: [`Dotenv` loads them into `$_ENV` while also doing a `putenv`.](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv/blob/master/Dotenv.php#L81). Could you post your OS, PHP version, and PHP compile flags, please? Because this may be an engine bug, possibly [#74986](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74986)

Comment: Just added it to the original post. I am on Win10 x64, using PHP v5.6.31

Comment: Ok, I'm going to _lean_ toward a bug with PHP 5.6 on Windows, however: putting into the environment is not always reliable. Reading from $_ENV is the robust solution here.

Comment: I have spent hours pulling my hair. Using $_ENV did solve the problem with 2 concurrent HTTP requests resulting in different results.